# How to pass Error Messages in Multiple languages for unobtrusive validations in MVC4

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4

How can I pass country specific customized text while displaying errors for  unobtrusive validations.

Thank
Mastan

Answer (score 0):

Create resource files for the languages you want to support. For each non-default language, it should end with the language's code, such as "es-es.resx" or "pt-pt.resx".
In the validation attributes, for example, RequiredAttribute, do not specify the ErrorMessage, but instead the ErrorMessageResourceType and ErrorMessageResourceName. In ErrorMessageResourceType specify the name of the class for a resource (.resx) item, and in ErrorMessageResourceName, its name.